# Which solutions are available for meta configuration or configuration verification?

Tags: java, validation, configuration

I want to develop a description language which enables developers to declare which possible configuration settings are valid for their software artifact. 
For example, you could declare that a port has to be a number between 8004 and 8010. Later on, I'd like to be able to define dependences between artifacts and how different artifacts can be composed. The field of operation is suppossed to be java application servers. 
The important thing is that you don't configure an artifact, but you define the set of possible values.
The next step would be to implement a tool that can check whether or not an actual configuration satifies the corresponding description.

Does anyone know tools or solutions --- preferably in the java world --- that I could (re)use for any of the given goals? I've already looked at configuration management tools like puppet or cfengine, but I found that they don't provide sufficient description capabilities and more useful for doing actual configurations. Perhaps I've just looked at them the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I thought reading you question is XSD and XML pair.
Application uses configurations from XML. But first of all app must validate XML file using specific XSD.

Comment: That is definitely one possible implementation approach. However,the goal of my question was primarily finding existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has [an article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) that lists several competing schema validation languages for XML. Perhaps one of those will provide you with inspiration.

Outside of XML, the only configuration format I can think of that provides schema validation is Config4* ([www.config4star.org](http://www.config4star.org)). Documentation is available in PDF and HTML formats. For your convenience, here are links to an [overview](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/overview-of-the-config4star-api.html#sect%3aintro%3aprog-api%3aschema-validation) of the Config4* schema language, and its [full definition](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/the-config4star-schema-language.html).

Disclaimer: I am the developer of Config4*.